# Duplicate a plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, duplicates

I need to use 2 versions of the wordpress plugin called popular_posts_plugin, set up to do different things. The problem is that the plugins interfere with each other and the core will shut one of them down.

I tried changing the name of all occurrences of popular_posts to popular_postsA in one of them along with all other identicalness I could find but it is still interfering.

How would this be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer actively maintains this project and says he will answer your questions or do custom development as requested. Ask him for help, he even provides his email.

```
me@cabrerahector.com
```

The plugin writes its values to the wordpress database, so you can't just rename stuff and expect it to work.

You can use shortcodes with this plugin, so if you want it to do different things then you may be able to use shortcode parameters to accomplish this.